# Error call to undefined function move_uploaded_file() after update from 5.63 to 5.69

Tags: contributions

I have recently updated CiviCRM on a Joomla site from 5.63.3 to 5.69.2.

Since this update, I have a error when submitting a contribution from frontend in which there is a form with a possibility to upload a file:

*call to undefined function move_uploaded_file()*

It works well when no file is submitted.

PHP version is 8.2, I tried also with 8.0, 8.1 & 7.4, and same error.

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That seems very odd because [move_uploaded_file()](https://www.php.net/move_uploaded_file) is a built-in PHP function.

Are you using shared hosting?  Because of security implications, it's quite possible your host has disabled this function.  If so, please open a support request with your host.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
That's was the issue, I contacted my host and the function was disabled.
Now it works well